# Android: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs with Braintree

Tags: android, android-manifest, braintree

I am getting this error when I add `Braintree dependency.`

**Execution failed** for `task ':vtg:processDevDebugManifest'.`

> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

### Braintree version: app Gradle

```
implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:5.3.0'
```

### project Gradle :

```
maven {
    url "https://cardinalcommerceprod.jfrog.io/artifactory/android"
    credentials {
        username 'braintree_team_sdk'
        password 'AKCp8jQcoDy2hxSWhDAUQKXLDPDx6NYRkqrgFLRc3qDrayg6rrCbJpsKKyMwaykVL8FWusJpp'
    }
}
```

I checked the `Merged Manifest` tab but I cannot see any error over there.

**What could be the cause?**